# Fading Between Divs

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to switch between a bunch of different divs, but the change is instant right now and I want to do more of a quick fade (maybe like the slideshow on the bottom here: http://responsiveslides.com/). Here's what I have right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showDiv(idInfo) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('divLinks').getElementsByTagName('div');
  for (var i=0; i<sel.length; i++) {
    sel[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById('container'+idInfo).style.display = 'block';
}
</script>

<div id="containerh"><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('1');return false"><img src="images/peach1.jpg" /></a></div>
<div id="container1"><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('2');return false"><img src="images/peach2.jpg" /></a></div>
<div id="container2"><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('3');return false"><img src="images/peach3.jpg" /></a></div>
<div id="container3"><a href="#" onclick="showDiv('4');return false"><img src="images/peach4.jpg" /></a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/). As an example (FYI, I learnt this on [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').click(function() {
        $('div').fadeOut('slow'); // alternatively use fadeIn
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple CSS + Javascript version. Using CSS transition.

#### » [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/t2k5e/) «

When `show()` is called display picture number `i` + hide previous if any.

```
var a = 0, img = null;
function show(i) {
    if (img)
        img.className = "hide";
    img = document.getElementById(a ? "img1" : "img2");
    a ^= 1;
    
    img.src = images[i];
    img.className = "show";
}
```

Called by:

```
<a href="#" onclick="show(3)">Picture 3</a>
```

CSS, main part:

Two image placeholders placed atop of each other.

```
img {
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
img.show {
    opacity : 1
}
.hide {
    opacity : 0;
}
```

---

This is only meant as a scratch sample.